# ASP.NET MVC 5 Storing identity users in Oracle database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-identity

I'm pretty new to developing ASP.NET apps, I started a new project and I'm using a Oracle DB with the ODP and OLAC plugins. I set up my connection string and I can see the database under the Server Explorer.

Now I want the Identity users to be stored on my DB too, but I cannot find where they are being stored right now. The app_data folder is empty, there are no .mdf files anywhere, my connection string is the Oracle connection string; but when I set up the IdentityDBContext to use my own connection string I get an error saying **"The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context."** I'm using a database-first approach:

This is the autogenerated code for my DB context:

```
public partial class ActivoContext : DbContext
{
    public ActivoContext()
        : base("name=ActivoContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
......
```

This is the Identity code generated by the project, I just changed the connection string:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=ActivoContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ActivoContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Activo.csdl|res://*/Activo.ssdl|res://*/Activo.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/xe;PASSWORD=activos;USER ID=ACTIVOS&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**EDIT**
So I realized the problem is having two different Contexts using the same connection string. Because of this, only one shows up and the other one doesnt work: the auto-generated db-first ActivoContext shows up and ApplicationDbContext doesnt. How should I go about merging these two or making them work together? I can't modify DbContext cause its auto-generated...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally got Identity 2.0 to work with my Oracle DB. Here's what I did:

The following steps work if you don't want to make any changes to the default IdentityUser (ex. if you're ok with having a char ID instead of int or long) and just want the tables on your existing Oracle schema.

1) Create Identity tables on Oracle. You can change the table names if you want to, just make sure to include the necessary columns for Identity to work with it. You can also add any extra columns you may need on your application (script originally found on [Devart](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Identity-2-Tutorial.html#scriptimg), I copied it to a gist in case URL breaks):

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/andresbejar/41431c27086ced7654fc7a3a06cbc58a)

2) If you're using an EDMX file, you need to add a new connection string cause the one that gets generated automatically won't work, you need a standard connection string. Try following this template:

```
<add name="IdentityContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost:1521/xe;PASSWORD=password;USER ID=username;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

3) Tell your ApplicationDbContext to use your new connectionString

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
: base("IdentityContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
}
```

4) Tell Identity to use your existing schema and tables. Add this method inside the ApplicationDbContext definition found in IdentityModels.cs:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // MUST go first.

modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YOUR_SCHEMA"); // Use uppercase!

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
}
```

5) Rebuild and thats it!

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction with getting Oracle set up finally with the default MVC template.

Comment: Hello.Can you share the code of ApplicationDbContext? And what Entitty framework do you use?

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use This Script to Create identity table Properly in Oracle DB

`

```
CREATE TABLE incapp.AspNetRoles (   
  Id VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,  
  Name VARCHAR2(256) NOT NULL  
 ) pctfree 20 pctused 70 tablespace INCTBL;  
 create unique index incapp.pk_aspnetroles on incapp.AspNetRoles (  
  id  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 alter table incapp.AspNetRoles add (  
  constraint pk_aspnetroles  
  primary key (id)  
 );  
 create public synonym AspNetRoles for incapp.AspNetRoles;  
 grant select,insert,update,delete on aspnetroles to webapps;  
 CREATE TABLE incapp.AspNetUserRoles (   
  UserId VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,  
  RoleId VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL  
 ) pctfree 20 pctused 70 tablespace INCTBL;  
 create unique index incapp.pk_AspNetUserRoles on incapp.AspNetUserRoles (  
  UserId, RoleId  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 alter table incapp.AspNetUserRoles add (  
  constraint pk_AspNetUserRoles  
  primary key (UserId, RoleId)  
 );  
 create public synonym AspNetUserRoles for incapp.AspNetUserRoles;  
 grant select,insert,update,delete on incapp.AspNetUserRoles to webapps;  
 CREATE TABLE incapp.AspNetUsers (   
  Id VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,  
  Email VARCHAR2(256) NULL,  
  EmailConfirmed NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,  
  PasswordHash VARCHAR2(256) NULL,  
  SecurityStamp VARCHAR2(256) NULL,  
  PhoneNumber VARCHAR2(256) NULL,  
  PhoneNumberConfirmed NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,  
  TwoFactorEnabled NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,  
  LockoutEndDateUtc TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,  
  LockoutEnabled NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,  
  AccessFailedCount NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,  
  UserName VARCHAR2(256) NOT NULL  
 ) pctfree 20 pctused 70 tablespace INCTBL;  
 create unique index incapp.pk_AspNetUsers on incapp.AspNetUsers (  
  id  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 alter table incapp.AspNetUsers add (  
  constraint pk_AspNetUsers  
  primary key (id)  
 );  
 create public synonym AspNetUsers for incapp.AspNetUsers;  
 grant select,insert,update,delete on incapp.AspNetUsers to webapps;  
 CREATE TABLE AspNetUserClaims (   
  Id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,  
  UserId VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,  
  ClaimType VARCHAR2(256) NULL,  
  ClaimValue VARCHAR2(256) NULL  
 ) pctfree 20 pctused 70 tablespace INCTBL;  
 create unique index incapp.pk_AspNetUserClaims on incapp.AspNetUserClaims (  
  id  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 alter table incapp.AspNetUserClaims add (  
  constraint pk_AspNetUserClaims  
  primary key (id)  
 );  
 create public synonym AspNetUserClaims for incapp.AspNetUserClaims;  
 grant select,insert,update,delete on incapp.AspNetUserClaims to webapps;  
 CREATE SEQUENCE incapp.AspNetUserClaims_SEQ;  
 create public synonym AspNetUserClaims_SEQ for incapp.AspNetUserClaims_SEQ;  
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER incapp.AspNetUserClaims_INS_TRG  
  BEFORE INSERT ON incapp.AspNetUserClaims  
  FOR EACH ROW  
 BEGIN  
  :NEW.Id := AspNetUserClaims_SEQ.NEXTVAL;  
 END;  
 /  
 CREATE TABLE incapp.AspNetUserLogins (   
  LoginProvider VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,  
  ProviderKey VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,  
  UserId VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL  
 ) pctfree 20 pctused 70 tablespace INCTBL;  
 create unique index incapp.pk_AspNetUserLogins on incapp.AspNetUserLogins (  
  LoginProvider, ProviderKey, UserId  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 alter table incapp.AspNetUserLogins add (  
  constraint pk_AspNetUserLogins  
  primary key (LoginProvider, ProviderKey, UserId)  
 );  
 create public synonym AspNetUserLogins for incapp.AspNetUserLogins;  
 grant select,insert,update,delete on incapp.AspNetUserLogins to webapps;  
 create unique index incapp.RoleNameIndex on incapp.AspNetRoles (  
  name  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 alter table incapp.AspNetRoles add (  
  constraint uq_RoleNameIndex  
  unique (name)  
 );  
 create index incapp.IX_AspNetUserRoles_UserId on incapp.AspNetUserRoles (  
  UserId  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 create index incapp.IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId on incapp.AspNetUserRoles (  
  RoleId  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 create unique index incapp.UserNameIndex on incapp.AspNetUsers (  
  UserName  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 create index incapp.IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId on incapp.AspNetUserClaims (  
  UserId  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 create index incapp.IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId on incapp.AspNetUserLogins (  
  UserId  
 ) pctfree 10 tablespace incidx;  
 ALTER TABLE incapp.AspNetUserRoles  
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserRoles_Roles FOREIGN KEY (RoleId) REFERENCES incapp.AspNetRoles (Id)  
  ON DELETE CASCADE;  
 ALTER TABLE incapp.AspNetUserRoles  
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserRoles_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES incapp.AspNetUsers (Id)  
  ON DELETE CASCADE;  
 ALTER TABLE incapp.AspNetUserClaims  
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserClaims_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES incapp.AspNetUsers (Id)  
  ON DELETE CASCADE;  
 ALTER TABLE incapp.AspNetUserLogins  
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserLogins_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES incapp.AspNetUsers (Id)  
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

`

Modify ConnectionString Like Below

```
<add name="DBContext" connectionString="Data Source=AAAA:1521/AA;PASSWORD=AAAA;USER ID=AAAA;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

Then Modify your OnModelCreating method Like This

`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
     {  
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);  
       modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("AAAAA");
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("USERNAME");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.AccessFailedCount).HasColumnName("ACCESSFAILEDCOUNT");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.LockoutEnabled).HasColumnName("LOCKOUTENABLED");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.LockoutEndDateUtc).HasColumnName("LOCKOUTENDDATEUTC");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled).HasColumnName("TWOFACTORENABLED");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasColumnName("PHONENUMBERCONFIRMED");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.PhoneNumber).HasColumnName("PHONENUMBER");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SECURITYSTAMP");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PASSWORDHASH");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("EMAILCONFIRMED");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnName("EMAIL");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERS").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("ID");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERROLES").Property(p => p.RoleId).HasColumnName("ROLEID");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERROLES").Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("USERID");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERLOGINS").Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("USERID");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERLOGINS").Property(p => p.ProviderKey).HasColumnName("PROVIDERKEY");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERLOGINS").Property(p => p.LoginProvider).HasColumnName("LOGINPROVIDER");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERCLAIMS").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("ID");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERCLAIMS").Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("USERID");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERCLAIMS").Property(p => p.ClaimType).HasColumnName("CLAIMTYPE");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETUSERCLAIMS").Property(p => p.ClaimValue).HasColumnName("CLAIMVALUE");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETROLES").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("ID");  
       modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()  
       .ToTable("ASPNETROLES").Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("NAME");  
     }
```

`

This Worked fine with my project.

You can find some interesting points in here. (ASP.NET MVC, EF with NgGet Oracle 12.2.1..)

[ASP.NET Identity With Oracle Database](http://codestreetblog.blogspot.com/2018/06/aspnet-identity-with-oracle-database.html)

Comment: Please, do not rely on links only your answers. Links may stop working and the post becomes useless. Please, try to explain a bit more in your post.

Comment: @Ondrej K. Thank you for the tip. I will update my answer. Let me know is there anything wrong with answer.